# In QGIS 2.16.1 and 2.16.2 no Raster Calculator available anymore

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

In all my older versions the raster calculator is easy to find in the raster menu - however in both 2.16. versions, it is not visible. As I understand this does not have anything to do if GdalTools is active or not.

I heard from one other user that she can see the Raster calculator in 2.12.2.

My setup is on a windows 10 PC.

Anyone else with the same problem?

Comment: I have a 2.16.2 OSgeo4w install on my win 10 computer and the raster calculator is the first option under the raster menu.

Comment: From the OP's [comment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209203/in-qgis-2-16-1-and-2-16-2-no-raster-calculator-available-anymore/209214#comment318530_209214), this issue **can** be reproduced as it seems the option to show the _Raster Calculator_ was disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things you could try:

---

- **GUI Customization**

  1. From the menubar, go to:

     ```
     Settings > Customization
     ```
  2. Then make sure this option is enabled:

     ```
     Menus > mRasterMenu > mActionShowRasterCalculator
     ```

     [image: Customization]
  3. Click *Apply* and *OK* then restart QGIS.

---

- **Access from Shortcut**

  1. From the menubar, go to:

     ```
     Settings > Configure shortcuts
     ```
  2. Then find the `Raster Calculator...` action and assign it a shortcut:

     [image: Configure shotcuts]
  3. Click *Close* then restart QGIS.

Comment: Hi Joseph, great stuff! Worked immediately! I'm a bit puzzled why those settings had been disabled or not active in the 2.16. Versions, since I haven't done anything different during the installation process. But anyhow. Now a) it's working nicely again  and b) I learned in general where to check if something in the menu doesn't shoes up.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BenjaminBauhaus - Most welcome, glad it was help! That is indeed strange, although I'm also a bit puzzled as to why your question has been put on hold...